# Problem “Didn't find PN53x board” Arduino NFC Card Reader

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, rfid, code-review

i am using the elechouse PN532 RFID Module with an Wemos D1 mini in the Arduino IDE.
I use the ISO1443a_uid example from the elechouse library. All works fine if i plug the USB Cable into the wemos and the demo runs. But if i press the reset button on the Wemos D1 mini then the Serial brings this output:

```
load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0x2d
csum 0x2d
v0fd86a07
~ld
Hello!
Didn't find PN53x board
```

Sometimes it works fine but mostly comes this error.

Here is the sample code (i am using the I2C Mode):

```
* When the number after #if set as 1, it will be switch to SPI Mode*/
if 0
 #include <SPI.h>
 #include <PN532_SPI.h>
 #include "PN532.h"

 PN532_SPI pn532spi(SPI, 10);
 PN532 nfc(pn532spi);

* When the number after #elif set as 1, it will be switch to HSU Mode*/
elif 0
 #include <PN532_HSU.h>
 #include <PN532.h>

 PN532_HSU pn532hsu(Serial1);
 PN532 nfc(pn532hsu);

* When the number after #if & #elif set as 0, it will be switch to I2C Mode*/
else 
 #include <Wire.h>
 #include <PN532_I2C.h>
 #include <PN532.h>
 #include <NfcAdapter.h>

 PN532_I2C pn532i2c(Wire);
 PN532 nfc(pn532i2c);
endif

oid setup(void) {
 Serial.begin(115200);
 Serial.println("Hello!");
 pinMode(D2,INPUT_PULLUP);
 pinMode(D1,INPUT_PULLUP);  
 nfc.begin();

 uint32_t versiondata = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();
 if (! versiondata) {
   Serial.print("Didn't find PN53x board");
   while (1); // halt
 }

 // Got ok data, print it out!
 Serial.print("Found chip PN5"); Serial.println((versiondata>>24) & 0xFF, HEX); 
 Serial.print("Firmware ver. "); Serial.print((versiondata>>16) & 0xFF, DEC); 
 Serial.print('.'); Serial.println((versiondata>>8) & 0xFF, DEC);

 // Set the max number of retry attempts to read from a card
 // This prevents us from waiting forever for a card, which is
 // the default behaviour of the PN532.
 nfc.setPassiveActivationRetries(0xFF);

 // configure board to read RFID tags
 nfc.SAMConfig();

 Serial.println("Waiting for an ISO14443A card");


oid loop(void) {
 boolean success;
 uint8_t uid[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };  // Buffer to store the returned UID
 uint8_t uidLength;                        // Length of the UID (4 or 7 bytes depending on ISO14443A card type)

 // Wait for an ISO14443A type cards (Mifare, etc.).  When one is found
 // 'uid' will be populated with the UID, and uidLength will indicate
 // if the uid is 4 bytes (Mifare Classic) or 7 bytes (Mifare Ultralight)
 success = nfc.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, &uid[0], &uidLength);

 if (success) {
   Serial.println("Found a card!");
   Serial.print("UID Length: ");Serial.print(uidLength, DEC);Serial.println(" bytes");
   Serial.print("UID Value: ");
   for (uint8_t i=0; i < uidLength; i++) 
   {
     Serial.print(" 0x");Serial.print(uid[i], HEX); 
   }
   Serial.println("");
   // Wait 1 second before continuing
   delay(1000);
 }
 else
 {
   // PN532 probably timed out waiting for a card
   Serial.println("Timed out waiting for a card");
 }
```

What is wrong? why is it not alltimes working after a reset?

Comment: I've had one of those `elechouse` PN532's sitting in a drawer waiting for the right project to come along - wow!! they sure are flakey in I2C mode - little less flakey when I added pullup resistors to SCL and SDA - but 50/50 at best - never had an issue with it in SPI mode

Comment: I2C on the PN532, at least using the library you are using, is not very reliable - even with adafruit library and using IRQ and RESET pins, it's still a 50/50 chance that the board is detected. I've tried many things to make mine work and have come to the conclusion that I should either use SPI or HSU mode - these are 100% reliable - and since I'll only ever need to read NFC tags, I think I'll stick to the MFRC522

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
Try using [Elechouse library](https://github.com/elechouse/PN532), it worked better for me.

---

This might be irrelevant, but I wanted to share.

I had a similar issue, not related to the sketch code.

So make sure:

1. Connect wires to the NFC module at **90 degrees** - there should be angular headers included. Also the wires should be **above the antenna** - the white strip.
2. There shouldn't be any wires underneath the NFC module or they should on significant distance.
3. Soldered wires work better on the NFC module.

[image: Stable working condition]